# Not understanding - recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am new to R parallel processing, I'm trying to move this from a  very slow working for-loop to multithread and this I cant figure out `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :  one node produced an error: promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?`

my xml wrangling is poor but this serves the purpose. The error comes from

```
process_entry <- function(ent,component_entry,  flattenXMLx=flattenXMLx, EntryComponent=EntryComponent, componentv=componentv){     
    
    library(data.table)
    flat<-NULL
    path <- character(0)
    df <-  data.frame(elem. = character(0), templateID = character(0), elemid. = integer(0), attr. = character(0), value. = character(0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
    component<-list()
    component[["Document"]][["block"]][["Body"]][['component']][['section']]<-component_entry[ent]
    
    entryc<-component[["Document"]][["block"]][["Body"]][['component']][['section']][['entry']][['organ']]
    
    y <- list()
        
    for (a in  1:length(entryc)) {
        if (any(names(entryc[a]) != "component")) {
            y = c(y, a)
        }
    }
    
    if (length(y)>0){
        entry_component <- component_entry[[ent]]$organizer
    } else{  
        entry_component<-NULL
    }
       
    if (any(length(entry_component)>0)){
        entcom<- EntryComponent(entry_component)
    } else {
        entcom<-NULL
    }
    
    componente <- flattenXMLx(xml2::xml_root(xml2::as_xml_document(component)), df, path)

    if(any(!is.na(entcom))){
        componente <<- dplyr::bind_rows(componente,entcom)}
    
    componentv <<- dplyr::bind_rows(componentv, componente)
    
    return(componentv)
}
```

this calls the function

```
componentv <- do.call(cbind, parLapply(cl, 1:length(component_entry), process_entry, component_entry=component_entry) )
```

the issue seems to come from `componentv <<- dplyr::bind_rows(componentv, componente)`

Comment: It's my understanding that you can't use super assignment like this `<<-` within a parallelized lapply. For parallelization to work, the iterations in lapply can't affect each other.  Your multiple processes are trying to change one object at once.

Comment: Parallelization in R is almost always done best in a purely functional semantic, meaning the function "knows" what is explicitly passed in the function's arguments (with exceptions, of course), and it can only influence what it itself generates or stores internally. As SmokeyShakers suggested, even if that functioned without erring or warning, I don't know what I would expect to happen in light of mutex problems. Exclusive read/write access to global objects can be a very fragile thing (see python and it's GIL), and R is not well known for its multi-threading robustness in this context.

Comment: If your `component_entry` argument, or returned value `componentv`, contains **xml2** objects, then it won't work.  Such objects can _not_ be sent transferred between R processes (here between the main R session and the parallel R workers).  You can read more about this problem in <https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html>

Comment: @HenrikB I believe this may be my issue. thanks so much I would have searched for days to find this.